# How to show a text from wx module?

Tags: python, wxwidgets

Yesterday found out that my router can be controlled by telnet, and today I was looking for some qt4,pygtk or wx to store all the router telnet commands in a gui. Less than 15 minutes ago I found this website - zetcode(dot)com/wxpython/advanced/ , which got the right information that I need. Unfortunatelly I don't understand how to include text in wx modules, because I am using it for a first time. Can you tell me how to assign text to the left window, because once I start the module it shows me a grey screen with a buttons in it's menu. The grey area that is the most left must contain around 10 telnet commands, where the "help" contains all of the commands saved in a html file.

```
import wx
import wx.html as html

class HelpWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(570, 400))
        toolbar = self.CreateToolBar()
        toolbar.AddLabelTool(1, 'Exit', wx.Bitmap('icons/exit.png'))
        toolbar.AddLabelTool(2, 'Help', wx.Bitmap('icons/help.png'))
        toolbar.Realize()

        self.splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self, -1)
        self.panelLeft = wx.Panel(self.splitter, -1, style=wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)

        self.panelRight = wx.Panel(self.splitter, -1)
        vbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        header = wx.Panel(self.panelRight, -1, size=(-1, 20))
        header.SetBackgroundColour('#6f6a59')
        header.SetForegroundColour('WHITE')
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        st = wx.StaticText(header, -1, 'Help', (5, 5))
        font = st.GetFont()
        font.SetPointSize(9)
        st.SetFont(font)
        hbox.Add(st, 1, wx.TOP | wx.BOTTOM | wx.LEFT, 5)

        close = wx.BitmapButton(header, -1, wx.Bitmap('icons/fileclose.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG),
        style=wx.NO_BORDER)
        close.SetBackgroundColour('#6f6a59')
        hbox.Add(close, 0)
        header.SetSizer(hbox)

        vbox2.Add(header, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        help = html.HtmlWindow(self.panelRight, -1, style=wx.NO_BORDER)
        help.LoadPage('wx.html')
        vbox2.Add(help, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.panelRight.SetSizer(vbox2)
        self.panelLeft.SetFocus()

        self.splitter.SplitVertically(self.panelLeft, self.panelRight)
        self.splitter.Unsplit()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.CloseHelp, id=close.GetId())
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.OnClose, id=1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TOOL, self.OnHelp, id=2)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKeyPressed)

        self.CreateStatusBar()

        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    def OnClose(self, event):
        self.Close()

    def OnHelp(self, event):
        self.splitter.SplitVertically(self.panelLeft, self.panelRight)
        self.panelLeft.SetFocus()

    def CloseHelp(self, event):
        self.splitter.Unsplit()
        self.panelLeft.SetFocus()

    def OnKeyPressed(self, event):
        keycode = event.GetKeyCode()
        if keycode == wx.WXK_F1:
            self.splitter.SplitVertically(self.panelLeft, self.panelRight)
            self.panelLeft.SetFocus()


app = wx.App()
HelpWindow(None, -1, 'HelpWindow')
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it...

```
wx.StaticText(self.panelLeft, -1, 'thetextgoeshere', (15, 5))
```